# jqGrid returning only records as defined in rowNum if using loadonce:true

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, rownum

Is this normal or I'm missing something?

If I set `loadonce: true`, my grid is returning only 5 records.

But if I change it to `loadonce: false`, the grid is getting all the records

My code is below.

```
$("#leave-detail-grid").jqGrid({
    url:'grid/grid_leave_detail.php',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['Date','Day','Approver','Leave Type','Status','Purpose | Reason'],
    colModel :[
      {name:'start_date', index:'start_date', width:80, editable:false, align:"left", editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'day', index:'day', width:80, editable:false, align:"left", editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'sup', index:'sup', width:130, editable:false, align:"left", editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'desc', index:'desc', width:130, editable:false, align:"left", editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'status', index:'status', width:80, editable:false, align:"center", editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'purpose', index:'purpose', width:180, editable:false, align:"left", editrules:{required:true}}    
    ],
    height: 'auto',
    pager: '#leave-detail-pager',
    pgbuttons: true,
    pginput: 'Yes',
    pgtext: 'Yes',
    rowNum:5,
    rowList:[20,40,100,200,400],
    sortname: 'start_date',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    loadonce: true, // to enable sorting on client side
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Search Purpose'
});
$("#leave-detail-grid").jqGrid('navGrid',"#leave-detail-pager",
      {edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true},
      {zIndex:5234},{zIndex:5234},{zIndex:5234},{zIndex:5234}
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Jonathan. How did I miss that demo :)

I add the colModel `rowTotal: 2000,` value -1 is not working, this will show 2000 recs

then add the below to my server code

```
$totalrows = isset($_REQUEST['totalrows']) ? $_REQUEST['totalrows']: false;
if($totalrows) {
$limit = $totalrows;
}
```

And to load all the records we need to tweak the server code to override the rowTotal parameter.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM leaveform WHERE emp_id='$emp_id'   AND company_id='$company_id'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
$count = $row['count']; 
$totalrows =  $count;
$limit = $totalrows;
```

Answer (score 1):

`rowNum:5,` means that the grid will only use 5 rows.

`loadonce: true` means that it will only load once.  It also disables the pager.

Based on this configuration, that grid will only use 5 rows, and since it will not load anymore from the server, it will always be the same 5.

Here a link to the Wiki which has the latest options documentation: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Comment: Thanks. I have thousands of data and I want to load it once, if I increase the rowNum, my grid size will also increase and its really ugly. There must be a way to manipulate date on client side for huge datasets.

Comment: @genpet Set rowNum to -1 will remove the limit.  Then, enable the pager and load all data at once.  It should work fine.

Comment: @genpet Go to this link: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html  Then, on the left side, scroll down to "New in Version 3.7" The second option is "Load at once from server".  That example seems to show what you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `loadonce: true` the server should return **all** rows. the data should be sorted coresponds to `sortname` and `sortorder` parameters which will be send to the server as `sidx` and `sord`.

The first page of the returned data will be displayed. You will be still able to use local paging, sorting and filtering (searching) of the data.

It could be important to define [sorttype](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) parameter to allow correct local sorting of the data.

If you still have the problem you should append your question with the XML response from the server. So other reader of your question would be able to reproduce the problem.

The last remark: you use very strange values for `pginput`, and `pgtext` options of jqGrid. You should better to hold the types of options described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions).

Comment: Thanks. rowTotal is the key and a little tweak on server code. Thanks as well on 'pginput' and 'pgtext'

Comment: @genpet: The server can ignore `rowTotal` and return just *all* records back. It's only a recommendation to the server, but it's not really important for working of jqGrid. On the first page will be displayed `rowNum` rows and *the paging should working* together with `loadonce: true`. I can repeat, that if you still have problems you should append your question with the XML data which you use (2-3 pages of data are enough).

Answer (score 0):

`{ rowNum: 0 }`  to set no limit rows...